how to find local storage is not defined?
ERROR ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
    at _TableComponent.loadUsers (F:\task\training2\src\app\table\table.component.ts:51:30)
    at ToastrService (F:\task\training2\src\app\table\table.component.ts:47:10)
    at callHookInternal (F:\task\training2\.angular\cache\18.2.4\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-S4UJ36BC.js:5640:10)
    at callHook (F:\task\training2\.angular\cache\18.2.4\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-S4UJ36BC.js:5655:7)
    at callHooks (F:\task\training2\.angular\cache\18.2.4\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-S4UJ36BC.js:5629:9)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (F:\task\training2\.angular\cache\18.2.4\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-S4UJ36BC.js:5598:5)
    at refreshView (F:\task\training2\.angular\cache\18.2.4\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-S4UJ36BC.js:10505:11)
    at detectChangesInView (F:\task\training2\.angular\cache\18.2.4\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-S4UJ36BC.js:10657:5)
    at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (F:\task\training2\.angular\cache\18.2.4\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-S4UJ36BC.js:10640:3)
    at detectChangesInComponent (F:\task\training2\.angular\cache\18.2.4\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-S4UJ36BC.js:10634:3)

like this came how to solve it
i was expecting what the problem of error

what's the content inside the table.component.ts

Look at the error log, it points to specific line in a specific file where the flow encountered an error. So, take a look at that line and if you cannot figure out what's the issue, then share the method where that line belongs.

If you are using SSR, see: how to author server-compatible components

try these ways
Syntax
window.localStorage

Save Data to Local Storage
localStorage.setItem(key, value);

Read Data from Local Storage
let lastname = localStorage.getItem(key);

Remove Data from Local Storage
localStorage.removeItem(key);

Remove All (Clear Local Storage)
localStorage.clear();


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
